# Create Specific Google Places or Maps Search Returns for Organic Restaurants

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm *slowly* building a travel app that will let users find organic, vegetarian, vegan type restaurants and businesses near them and on a route they are travelling. It looks like I can't have the results return ONLY places that deal with organic foods, instead of every restaurant near me. Can I get the returns that specifically? I searched the forum but unless I'm using the wrong search terms, it doesn't look like anyone else has had a similar issue. I've see only restaurants returns, only ATMs and so on. Am I missing something? I'm new to this, so all help is appreciated.

My app will do essentially what http://www.eatwellguide.org/travel_map does. I discovered they have built there own api, but I think there's a way to do the same through Places. I hope.

Comment: The text search doesn't seem to be returning only the organic, vegan, etc. places. It still get all results--McDonald's is definitely NOT organic. :)

Answer (score 0):

Google publishes a list of supported place types you can filter on here:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types

Organic, vegetarian, and vegan filters are not included.

However you can do text searches for the words "organic", "vegetarian", or "vegan", so maybe get closer to your goal that way.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests

Comment: If it works for you, mark it as your accepted answer so it can help other people with the same question.

Comment: Will do. Haven't had time to test this yet.